# Is it possible to migrate v1 Box accounts to V2 Box accounts without requiring user interaction?

Tags: authentication, box-api

I've updated my app to use the new Box V2 API instead of the old Box V1 API.

I have only one question left : 
Can I somehow login to Box V2 using the auth_token received from Box V1 without requiring user interaction (prompt for the user's password again)?

Thanks for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, since the two APIs use completely separate authentication systems ("V1 Auth" vs. OAuth 2), you'll need to send the user through the OAuth 2 flow in order to get an OAuth 2 access token – there isn't a method of "exchanging" a V1 auth token for an OAuth token.